# How to pass a table values to a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Brief Explanation:**
I have a dynamic table in where I add Products that have ID,NAME,PRICE,COST and TOTAL.

With a drop-down list full of products when I click a button a product is added to the table

The table has inputs inside in order to set the quantity and the total based on the price of the product.

The thing is, when the table is done, I need to handle the table values in the controller to do some stuff in SQL.

I have read some other similar cases but I think none is like mine.

**Example of my table with 1 product**

```
    <table id="tablaCompras" class="table table-striped table-responsive" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" name="tablaCompras">
    <tbody>
            <tr align="left">
                <th scope="col">Número Artículo</th>
                <th scope="col">Artículo</th>
                <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                <th scope="col">Costo Unitario</th>
                <th scope="col">Total</th>
                <th scope="col">Precio Unitario</th>
                <th scope="col">Impresión</th>
                <th scope="col">Eliminar</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="0" align="left"><td>31</td><td width="100%">ANILLO DE PLATA 030269</td><td> <input type="text" id="txtCantidadTabla0" value="0.00" name="txtCantidadTabla" 0min="1" style="background: transparent; border:none; align:center; max-width:100px;" onblur="getTotal(txtCantidadTabla0.value ,txtCostoTabla0.value,0)" required=""></td>
                <td> <input type="text" id="txtCostoTabla0" name="txtCostoTabla0" value="89.7" style="background: transparent; border:none; align:center; max-width:100px;" onblur="getTotal(txtCantidadTabla0.value ,txtCostoTabla0.value,0)" required="">  </td>
                <td> <input id="txtTotalTabla0" type="text" style="background: transparent; border:none; align:center; max-width:100px;" readonly=""> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" id="txtPrecioTabla0" name="txtPrecioTabla0" value="269.9" style="background: transparent; border:none; align:center; max-width:100px;" required=""></td>
                <td> <a href="#tabla"><img src="../Img/imprimir.png" style="width:30px; height:30px;"></a></td><td> <a href="#tabla"><img src="../Img/borrar.png" onclick="deleteRow(0)" style="width:30px; height:30px;"></a></td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have my table in a Html.BeginForm like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Prueba", "AltaCompra", FormMethod.Post))
{
}
```

In my controller I tried to receive it like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Prueba(FormCollection collection)
{
}
```

But Tables cannot be passed through to a formcollection.
Any clues of how can I handle the information of the table.

Comment: If you are going to do a form POST you should have a unique `name` on each input but it looks like each `tr` will repeat the input names. This is now more commonly handled via javascript and ajax with libraries like Angular that bind data for you.

Comment: https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Answer (score 1):

You need update your name for input with format `name="@("txtCantidadTabla[" + @i + "]")"`, incase you add new row by javascript/jQuery you must add name with this format.

```
 @for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) // I assume the total product
            {
                <tr id="0" align="left">
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="productid" value="31" />31</td>
                    <td width="100%">ANILLO DE PLATA 030269</td>
                    <td> <input type="text" id="@("txtCantidadTabla[" + @i + "]")" value="0.00" name="@("txtCantidadTabla[" + @i + "]")" 0min="1" style="background: transparent; border:none; align:center; max-width:100px;" onblur="getTotal(txtCantidadTabla0.value ,txtCostoTabla0.value,0)" required=""></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" id="@("txtCantidadTabla[" + @i + "]")" name="@("txtCostoTabla[" + @i + "]")" value="89.7" style="background: transparent; border:none; align:center; max-width:100px;" onblur="getTotal(txtCantidadTabla0.value ,txtCostoTabla0.value,0)" required="">  </td>
                    <td> <input id="txtTotalTabla0" type="text" style="background: transparent; border:none; align:center; max-width:100px;" readonly=""> </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" id="@("txtCantidadTabla[" + @i + "]")" name="@("txtPrecioTabla[" + @i + "]")" value="269.9" style="background: transparent; border:none; align:center; max-width:100px;" required=""></td>
                    <td> <a href="#tabla"><img src="../Img/imprimir.png" style="width:30px; height:30px;"></a></td>
                    <td> <a href="#tabla"><img src="../Img/borrar.png" onclick="deleteRow(0)" style="width:30px; height:30px;"></a></td>
                </tr>
            }
```

And get data by FormCollection in controller as

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Prueba(FormCollection collection)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var txtCantidadTabla = collection["txtCantidadTabla[" + i + "]"];
                var txtCostoTabla = collection["txtCostoTabla[" + i + "]"];
                var txtPrecioTabla = collection["txtPrecioTabla[" + i + "]"];

                // handle your logic here
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `id` of the `<tr>` matching the last character of the `name` attribute for the input elements you probably need to modify your code to generate the `name` attribute to have array notation around the index value such as `name="txtCostoTabla[0]"` where the index of the row is the hard coded index if you want multiple values submitted in the form POST with the same name.

Otherwise as suggested in a previous comment handle the form submit with JavaScript and build an object to pass to the Controller by iterating the table rows.